# Sync Adapter retries for Periodic sync

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

When there is a sync failure of a periodic sync, and if we have configured syncResult.stats.numIOExceptions++, sync manager retries using the exponential backoff algorithm.

We can stop the reschedule completely by setting SyncResult.tooManyRetries = true. But, is there a way to control the number of max retries and customize the delay between each sync retries?